# Using a long number to generate 2 unique long numbers

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, unique, long-integer

I have an application that uses a generated number, `eventNumber`, on an `Event Message`, as a message id to produce a `Notification Message`. `eventNumber` is guaranteed to be unique and increasing.

So for each genNum, we generate a notification message.

```
eventNumber on EventMsg | Notification Msg ID
---------------------------------------------
                23      |   23
                31      |   31
                37      |   37
```

We use the message id in a `Notification message` to track which `Event message` produced it. So let's say we had a Notification Message with ID `123`. With that ID `123`, we can say the Event message with `123` produced that Notification message.

The issue is that the there may be rare times where an Event message can requires the production of 2 notification messages. Since each `Notification Message` has to be unique, this is a problem.

Let's say we have an Event with ID `456` that requires us to produces 2 Notification messages.  This is a problem because we expect each notification message to have an unique Id. Meaning we can't use 456 as the  message ID for both notification messages.

Is there a way to still use the Event message ID `456`, to produce unique ID's for the 2 Notification messages? This resulting ID's should still make it possible to decode the fact that it came from Event with ID 456.

All id's/number of type long.

So far, my naive solution is for every Event ID, I multiply by `10` and then increment the second one. So
`456` becomes `4560`. Notification message 1 will have ID `4560` and `4561` respectively. Is there a better way to go about this? Thank you for taking the time to read this question

Comment: What is the problem with your way? Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Oleg I'm want to verify my implementation(logic) and also see if there's a better way.

Comment: (A) Will your system get confuses when the event ID eventually ratchets up to 4560 while you have existing message ID of 4560? (B) I suggest you learn about 128-bit UUIDs rather than putting effort into your own clever approach.

Comment: @BasilBourque Every Notification has a name field. So it only has to unique across names.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to make a unique number i used this method because there is so small change to be the number same as other generated;

```
long number;
public long unique(int number) {

this.number = number * number;
for(int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
if(this.number % i == 0) {
this.number = this.number / i;
break;
} 
}
return this.number;
}
```

Doesn’t properly work with prime numbers, but works!

Example first message id 8. This method will generate second id and it will be 32. It is simple to decode what was the first message number. This can also works with BigIntegers, but I never work with them and doesn’t know how to work with them.

You can make the number long by changing `public long unique(int number)` to `public BigInteger unique(long number)` and `long number;` to 
`BigInteger number;`

I made for you method to decode it. Be aware it works only sometimes!

```
double Squareroot;
public double find(long number) {
for(long i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
int testing = number * i;
Squareroot = Math.sqrt(test);
if(Squareroot == Math.floor(Squareroot) {
break;
}
}
return Squareroot;
}
```

Comment: The issue with prime numbers might be an issue. Nevertheless, you answer has shared some light on which direction I can possibly proceed. So thank you

Comment: I updated answer for decoding. It is my first idea how can I decode it and works only sometimes.

Comment: The prime numbers are working, but they are not divide.